# Submitting a form doesn't work after time, only after refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Simple Form and i just realized that if edit the form long enough (5-10secs) the Submit button suddenly doesn't work.

If i refresh the page and quickly type some letters and the submit it, it works...

This behavior is active on everything in my app that has a scaffold form, for example my Devise form's are just fine.

I have no idea what is causing this behavior.. What am i missing ?

**EDIT**

This behavior occurs only in Google Chrome Browsers.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
          <h1>Test Form</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
          <% if @question.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
                <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :title %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true,
                placeholder: "#"%>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :body %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :body, class: "redactor redactor-box" %>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel-footer">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in the HTML.
I wrapped all my html tags with form_for and for now it seems to be working..